# Script For F in *

Tags: bash, cygwin, sh

I am using Cygwin on Server 2012 r2

I have a script that I'm making to sort the files based on part of the filename which is the date.  Sorting them into a folder

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in * ; do
 if [[ $f == *_D????00_* ]] ;
  then
   if ! [[ -e ../2000/$f ]]
    echo "../2000/$f EXISTS"
 else
    echo "Copying $f --> ../2000/$f"
fi
done
```

I get this error:

```
$ ./sort.sh
./sort.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./sort.sh: line 8: ` else'
```

Fairly new to linux bash, especially cygwin.

Thoughts?

-Mike

Comment: cygwin is *not* Linux.

Comment: I believe Basile means, please fix your tags and title to accurately reflect the environment you’re using.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ - the problem becomes obvious quickly (I think) :)

Comment: Zak solved it below.  Very simple and basic.  Just characters disappearing after looking at a screen for too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did your `then` statement correctly once (ending it with `fi`) .. But then you forget to do it for the nested `if`  IE

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in * ; do
    if [[ $f == *_D????00_* ]]
    then
       if ! [[ -e ../2000/$f ]]
       then
            echo "../2000/$f EXISTS"
       else
            echo "Copying $f --> ../2000/$f"
       fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: DUH!!!

Thank you!  Sometimes you look at something for too long and things start to disappear!

This worked!